# Probability of combinatoric explosion.

Tags: probability

Someone posted a puzzle on a forum.

[image: crate puzzle]

Now this is fairly easy. Probability of reverse: The crate doesn't contain a unusual = the crate contains a weapon or none of two found crates contains a unusual. This produces a quadratic equation, I discard the solution outside the [0,1] range and substract the other one from 1 to get the answer.

The interesting part is the 5% of the 55% chance for 2 crates. If you open 1000 crates, you.  will end 
up with about 1100 new crates on the average and about no chance ever to reduce this number. It will only grow. You WILL get infinite number of crates if you start off with enough. Still, starting with just one you're quite likely not to get any specials.

Now what is the chance you will get the **infinite number of crates (and as result, unusuals)** if you start off with only one crate?

Comment: Your analysis of the problem looks wrong to me, what if the crate has 10 nested layers of specials, yet none of them have an unusual?

Comment: Shouldn't *The crate doesn't contain a special * say unusual?

Comment: Yes, corrected in all instances (I hope). With every layer you have 10%chance for unusual. 10 layers is >2^10, what is the chance none of 1024 crates contains an unusual?

Comment: Isn't this the equivalent of a random walk starting from 1?

Comment: @ike: Not entirely, since with biased random walk your chances to return to origin are diminished linearly, and here - with square of number of steps.

Comment: Open one special box at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found the solution for the question :

Let $p$, the probability of not having an unusual :

- Either you get a weapon
- or two crates without unusual

$$p=0.35+0.55*p^2$$

This polynomial have one root in $[0,1]$, hence

$$p=\frac{10-\sqrt{23}}{11}\approx 0.4731$$

---

Your question can be answered the same way :

Let $q$, the probability of having an infinite number of crates :

- You open two crates and at least one can lead to an infinite number of crates. This is the complementary of both crates not having infinite number of crates inside.

  $$q=0.55*(1-(1-q)^2)=0.55(-q^2+2q)$$

$$q(0.55q-0.1)=0 $$

That leads to two solutions : $q=0$ or $q=\frac{2}{11}$. But as you explained $q>0$ because the event "having infinite number of crates" is likely to happen if you have enough crates. Hence

$$q=\frac{2}{11}$$

Note that if you use $0.5$ or $0.45$ instead of $0.55$ the only valid solution is $0$.

Comment: *But as you explained q>0 because the event "having infinite number of crates" is likely to happen if you have enough crates.* Can you make that more rigorous?

Comment: I think the answer *is* q=0

Comment: @Ike More rigorous ? Yes. Let $X_t$ the number of crates at time $t$. Then $E(X_{t+1})=0.55(2E(X_t))=1.1E(X_t)$. Hence if $X_0=1$, then $E(X_t)=(1.1)^t$. So the mean of $X_t$ goes to infinity when $t$ goes to infinity. From that, we could see that probability of $X_{t+1}<X_t$ goes to 0. So $q>0$ obviously !

Comment: Your argument is incorrect because *if* X reaches 0, it sticks there.

Comment: @ike I'm talking about $E(X)$, not $X$. Try to understand what I mean about the mean.

Answer (score 1):

This is the extinction problem in [branching process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process#Extinction_problem)

The probabilty of extinction by generation (try) $m$ is given recursively by
$d_m=p_0 + p_2 (d_{m-2})^2$ with $p_0=0.45$ and $p_2=0.55$

The probabily of eventual extinction is obtained by finding a smaller than one root for $d=p_0 + p_2 (d)^2$. In our case: $d=9/11=0.8181...$

Then, the probability of opening infinite crates is $2/11=0.1818...$